# The extreme points of $z=x^3+y^3-(x+y)^2$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization

I am finding the extreme points of the function $z=x^3+y^3-(x+y)^2$.
This function has two critical points $(0;0)$ and $(4/3;4/3)$.
The second point is an extreme point.
For the first point, I have no conclusion.
I claimed it is not an extreme point.
Clear, $z<0$ when $x,y<0$. I am looking for $(x;y)$ such that $z>0$.
Am I correct?

Comment: Can you send the link?

Comment: Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Hint: look what happens when $y=-2x$

Comment: Could you please give a more detail? I look nothing

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Take $y = x^2-x$.

Comment: tks. What a right hint!

Answer (score 1):

The quadratic form in the Maclaurin expansion, $Q(x,y)=-(x+y)^2$, is negative semidefinite, so the second derivative test is inconclusive. Then it's usually a good idea to see what happens at the points where $Q=0$, since that's where the higher-order term may have a chance of making their voice heard.

So have a look at what happens along the line $y=-x$:
$$
f(t,-t) = \cdots
$$

EDIT:
Have a look at what happens along a curve which is tangent to the line $y=-x$ at the origin:
$$
f(t,-t+t^2) = \cdots
$$

Comment: But $f(t,-t)=0$. It is wrong

Comment: @zero: Of course, my mistake. Sorry about that! See the updated answer for something which actually works.